Movie with talking monkey puppet
I don't know if this was a strange dream or not, but I could swear that I remember a movie about a young boy and some kind of puppet (maybe). And the boy is dreaming about his funeral because I think he wasn't getting along with his parents or something. And then he goes in this like cave and finds a chest with the talking monkey puppet thing in it. At some point the boy and his talking monkey puppet are being chased by a butcher or like a pizza store owner? I think it was on Netflix but it isn't anymore.
It was an American film, and it looked like it came out in the 80s or 90s (or early 2000s?). I'm pretty sure I stopped watching the movie halfway through because it was not very good, so I don't know the ending. And the character was a boy of about maybe 11.

This is Munchie from 1992 that somehow starred Loni Anderson and a young Jennifer Love Hewitt.

In this in-name-only sequel to Munchies (1987), a new kid in town, Gage Dobson, can't find his place in the new environment despite having such a cool name. The kids at school bully him, the girl he likes doesn't register him and his mom is about to marry a scoundrel. Everything changes for Gage Dobson when he stumbles into Munchie, a friendly gremlin-like creature that dresses like a lounge singer, sounds like a stand-up comedian and has magic powers.

Gage often fantasizes about his own death and funeral, and finds Munchie (voiced by Dom DeLuise) in a chest in a cave. They both love pizza and are chased by a pizza chef at some point. The trailer:




...And if you could somehow bear it, there was also a sequel!
